# What is wrong with the following code, list box items don't get displayed?

Tags: wpf, list, templates, listbox, datatemplate

I want to display a listbox containng list items, I have the following template but it doesn't work, I also changed List l to ObservableList but still same result.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="list1"/>
```

```
List<String> l = new List<String>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list1.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("dataTemplate");
        l.Add("Hi");
        l.Add("there");

        list1.Items.Add(l);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<string>` does not have a property called `Items`, so your binding is invalid

To make it work, remove the path `Items` in the the binding so it binds directly to the list

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding }">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Xaml you're binding to an Observable collection called Items, in your code behind your just adding to the items property of the list.

You need to create an ObservableCollection in your code behind called Items, then add to that collection.

Comment: I changed l to an observable collection but still same result, if thats what you were referring to.

Comment: in the Xaml, since I am assigning the DataTemplate to the ItemsTemplate property of the list, Items refers to a property on the item that is added to the Listbox, which is a list, which has the Items property, correct me if I am wrong.